# PHP - How to connect 2 values in array

Tags: php

I have 2 values in array and i want to connect them.

Look at example above:

```
<?php
$a = array(
    'test' => 'localhost',
    'test2' => this->test .'/site'
);
?>
```

I want to connect value **test** with **/site**: **localhost/site**
I tried:

- this->test
- $a['test']
- test
- $test

And no one of them worked.

Comment: Why not simply: `$a['test2'] = $a['test'] . '/site';`?

Comment: You could also consider using textual references like `'%test%/site'` and then have some other code figure it out :)

Comment: @Jack, you're right, but i wanted all variables in one array, but your method is better and that is what i expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$domain = 'localhost';
$a = array(
    'test' => $domain,
    'test2' => $domain .'/site'
);
```

Or

```
$a = array('test' => 'localhost');
$a['test2'] => $a['test'] .'/site';
```

But you can't use `$this->` on an array, that's for objects.

Comment: I use second method, is better for this situation. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, but works.

```
$a = array(
    'test' => $test = 'localhost',
    'test2' => $test . '/site'
);
```

Comment: Your method is nice, but i use Jessica solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

maybe, you can use `implode` function, example

```
<?php
$a = array(
    'test' => 'localhost',
    'test2' => '/site'
);
$result = implode($a);
?>
```

Comment: In array i have'nt only 2 variables, so this method is good, but not for this situation. Anyway, thanks for answer.